# PDF font color appears grey instead of black

Tags: fonts, pdftex

[image: This is LYX generated PDF looks grey]

[image: This is word generated PDF looks black]

When I generate my PDF file from LYX. My PDF file text color appears grey as shown in the first image. I want a black color of the text as shown in the second image which is WORD generated PDF.

```
 \documentclass[12pt,english]{article}
`\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}

    \usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{color}
    \definecolor{document_fontcolor}{rgb}{0, 0, 0}
    \color{document_fontcolor}
    \usepackage{babel}
    \usepackage{float}
    \usepackage{textcomp}
    \usepackage{pdfpages}
    \usepackage{tipa}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{setspace}
    \usepackage{subscript}
    \doublespacing
    \usepackage[unicode=true,
     bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=false,bookmarksopen=false,
     breaklinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 0},backref=false,colorlinks=false]
     {hyperref}

    \makeatletter

    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
    \DeclareRobustCommand{\greektext}{%
      \fontencoding{LGR}\selectfont\def\encodingdefault{LGR}}
    \DeclareRobustCommand{\textgreek}[1]{\leavevmode{\greektext #1}}
    \DeclareFontEncoding{LGR}{}{}
    \DeclareTextSymbol{\~}{LGR}{126}
    %% Because html converters don't know tabularnewline
    \providecommand{\tabularnewline}{\\}
    %% A simple dot to overcome graphicx limitations
    \newcommand{\lyxdot}{.}


    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Textclass specific LaTeX commands.
    \numberwithin{equation}{section}

    \@ifundefined{date}{}{\date{}}
    \@ifundefined{showcaptionsetup}{}{%
     \PassOptionsToPackage{caption=false}{subfig}}
    \usepackage{subfig}
    \makeatother

    \begin{document}
```

Comment: is this on screen, or printed on paper?  (i ask, because the screen i work on fails to make almost *anything* appear solid black.)

Comment: It would be good to have a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. How could we possibly help you? Because if that was a general problem (i.e. all Lyx users, all documents), it would have been fixed already...

Comment: It appears grey both on screen and printed paper too

Comment: Then without access to an mwe it is impossible to help.

Comment: Could you please post a small, complete document starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}` which we can compile to reproduce the problem? Only include parts of your preamble which are required to reproduce the issue. For example, does the problem really disappear if you don't load `pdfpages` or `subfig` or any of the other apparently irrelevant packages?

Comment: Also, the first image looks black to me (or blacker), whereas the second seems mostly grey/blurry except for the sub-heading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that it is, in fact, the first image which is created by LaTeX and the first by Word, I take it that the following would be an adequate MWE (actually, not quite minimal but almost):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\paragraph{Heading}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]

If so, this is simply the default font, given that you are using the `T1` font encoding (as is recommended). Probably you are getting fonts from `cm-super`, which is what is shown in the image above from my compilation.

Without the `T1` encoding, you get the default, built-in fonts:

[image: default CM]

In both cases, the font is Computer Modern Roman. In the first case, it is an extended, type1 version; in the second, the default Metafont version.

Computer Modern Roman is a relatively light font. It is ***not*** being typeset in grey. If you print it, it will probably look darker, but it is still a relatively light font.

The fact that you are using double-spacing also makes the text look lighter: the image from Word does not have this feature although the font is clearly a heavier one, as well.

Here's the result with default spacing (still larger interline spacing than Word uses, of course):

[image: default spacing]

However, if you want a darker-looking font, just choose one with a heavier design. For example:

```
\usepackage{kpfonts}
```

[image: kpfonts]

```
\usepackage{tgschola}
```

[image: Tex-Gyre Schola]

```
\usepackage{tgpagella}
```

[image: Tex-Gyre Pagella]

```
\usepackage{venturis2}
```

[image: VenturisADF No2]

```
\usepackage{paratype}
```

[image: Paratype]